# github inconsistency in pushing to existing vs new repo

Tags: git, github

The gitHub account has ssh keys installed, in fact, from the directory of both existing and new repos:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi {github_username}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

neither repository has a deploy key attached.  Since August 14, 2021 (day after sunset on password access), I have been pushing successfully from existing repos.

```
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 38, done.
Counting objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 2.44 KiB | 2.44 MiB/s, done.
Total 20 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (17/17), completed with 16 local objects.
To github.com:{github_username/{existing_repo_name}.git
   78e8382..9a0dbc1  master -> master
```

All repositories are referred to via the ssh addressing:

```
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:{github_username}/{name_of_repo}.git'
```

However, a new repo created as of today will not push, as the prompt asks for the username and then password:

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': ^C
```

This is made a tad more absurd if a verbose test connection is run:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
[...]
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi {github_username}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3172, received 2520 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 8710.6, received 6920.2
debug1: Exit status 1

$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': {github_username}
Password for 'https://{github_username}@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/{github_username}/new_repo_name.git/'
```

How can this be forced to consistently use the ssh-key which both origin and master have?

Comment: It is clear that it's trying to use http and not ssh - adjust the remote URL.

Comment: check with `git remote -v`

Comment: ah yes, in ` git config`.  oddly, some automated process set the value incorrectly - then got carried over mindlessly.

Answer (score 0):

for reference, in the context of a rails app `.git/config` :

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:{github_username}/{repo_name}.git
```